# appending span is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 form=jQuery("<form>"
            ,{
                "method":"post"
                ,
                "action":node.get("inline-edit-target")

            }
            );


        $(node).after(form);
        //console.log($(node).html());

        fieldNode=$(node).find(".inline-edit-field");
        console.log(fieldNode.length);
        fieldNode.each(function(index,elem)
        {
            console.log($(elem).data("field-name"));

            $(form).append("<span>").html($(elem).data("field-name"));
            $(form).append("<input>"
                ,{
                    "type":"text"
                    ,
                    "name":$(elem).data("field-name")
                    ,
                    "value":$(elem).text()
                });       
        }
        );
```

Its basically check the DOM and prepare a form. form parses two fields correctly (fieldNode.length produce correct number). It also prints the nodes correctly untill i added the `span` tag. Why it is not working?

Comment: What's "not working"?  The span doesn't show up?  There's a JS error? The loop stops processing?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, if it's the only problem, is this line:

```
$(form).append("<span>").html($(elem).data("field-name"));
```

And stems from the fact that `append()` returns the original element to which the new element was appended, *not* the new element itself ([proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mJrKP/)).

So you're appending a `span` and then immediately over-writing the HTML of the parent div to whatever the `$(elem).data('field-name')` returns.

Also, you'll have a problem with the immediately-following line, since jQuery won't (or *can't*) create an element using an object, with append ([proof of failure](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mJrKP/1/)), instead you have to use a string of html, such as, in your case:

```
$(form).append('<input type="text" name="' + $(elem).data('field-name') + '" value="' + $(elem).text() + '" />');
```

*Or* (and this is perhaps easier):

```
$(form).append($("<input />" ,{
    "type" : "text",
    "name" : $(elem).data("field-name"),
    "value" : $(elem).text()
}));
```